# How to use data structures in interviews

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This question is about how to best approach a coding interview from a data structures point of view.

The way I see it, there are two different ways, I could implement a specific DS from scratch, initialise it and then use it to solve my problem, or simply use a library (I'm talking about Node.js here, but I guess this applies to other languages as well, at least those with some in-built support for DS) without worrying about the implementation and only focusing on how to use them to solve a problem.

In the first case, I'm also demonstrating that I can implement a specific DS from scratch, but at the same time I would need more time and there's some additional complexity. Instead, using a library would leave me more time to solve the actual problem, but some companies might take a dim view on this approach.

I know there's no silver bullet, and different companies will have different views, but what approach would you take if you could only pick one, and why?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This is not really a programming question, we have no way to know how some interviewer would perceive this or that tactic in an interview, and open-ended questions like this is not what this site is supposed to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Well it is always best to use the library but it is always better to know how common library functions work at least the basic ones.

For example, in many interviews Binary search is asked to be implemented instead of just using the library functions. This is because knowing the implementation adds some good concept which can be used in general problem solving like using the same concept in other divide and conquer algorithms.

In production level code we always look for the fail safe and properly tested library code.

Answer (score 0):

You should pick available libraries, first hand. If needed, customize the behavior of already available libraries.

Comment: This is the best approach not just for interviews but for programming as well. First choice is Library, Second choice is extend and modify from the Library.